# Want to hide specific element if the page if one condition is met

Tags: javascript

I have the text **New Delhi** under h2 in the HTML.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-boot-pad">
   <h2 class="head-travel-city">Abu Dhabi to New Delhi</h2>
</div>
```

The querySelector for above h2 is below. I want to run a condition, if the following querySelector has the text New Delhi in it,

```
document.querySelector("#flight-details-container > div:nth-child(1) >
       div.row.no-boot-md-mar > div > h2")
```

Then hide the following querySelector container.

```
document.querySelector("body > div:nth-child(32) > 
div.fade.ssh-modal.ssr-modal.in.modal > div > div > div.modal-body > 
form > div.pax-row.adult > div:nth-child(3) > div")
```

Comment: Please always add your attempted solution(s); do not simply state your problem and await for someone else to solve it. This will help you receive more answers and avoid down-votes.

Comment: Yes I understand but I am really a newbie to the JS. can't really explain things sometimes

Comment: that is a further reason to try; if you force yourself to explain what you already tried, you will have to think about the logic behind your code, which has two great effects: (1) you are more likely to identify by yourself where the problem is (and maybe even what the soultion could be) and (2) you get a better understanding on why your code works the way it does. Good luck with your learning journey. ;)

Comment: @secan, yes that makes sense, thanks for the encouragement :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have multiple elements with class ".head-travel-city".

```
let criteria = "New Delhi"

let cities = document.querySelectorAll(".head-travel-city");
[...cities].forEach(city => {
  if (city.innerText.contains(criteria)) {
    document.querySelector("give a proper selector as I did, your way is not good").style.display = "none";
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your time doing this for me.